# Find yesterday | last friday etc date in Unix Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, date

I used below code to find out yesterday and last friday 's date. It was working in server1.

```
YESTERDAY=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%m%d%Y")
echo YESTERDAY: $YESTERDAY;

LASTFRIDAY=$(date --date='last Friday' +"%m%d%Y")
echo LAST FRIDAY: $LASTFRIDAY;
```

I need to move the script to Server2 where it gives below error.

```
date: illegal option -- date=yesterday
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
YESTERDAY:
date: illegal option -- date=last Friday
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
LAST FRIDAY:
```

Can anyone please help me in fixing this. Any other reliable way to get this which can work on any server.

Comment: What is the exact operating system on 'Server2'?

Comment: Both are Unix Servers. Its just like one is Dev and other is QA.

Comment: As I read, There are two kinds of Date. GNU and BSD. Above commands should work fine in GNU based date system.

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` on 'Server2'?

Comment: It depends on whether server2 has GNU date installed and in the current path.

Comment: @Johnsyweb : I tried uname -a. It gave "SunO qa05s023 5.10 Generic_147440-15 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise"

Comment: @jim : How do I test if GNU date is installed or not?

Comment: To find which one is in your PATH: which date   ... On Solaris if that is /usr/bin/date then your PATH does not see GNU date.  Command: find /usr/local /opt/csw -name date : end command    will probably locate it. IF it exists.

Comment: @jimmcnamara : "which date" gives me /bin/date. while the "find" command gives me "access denied". Now in case GNU is not installed then anyway I can get yesterday's or last friday's date?

Comment: You have to resort to perl or ruby python - you can find examples here on stackoverflow.  Chris FA Johnson has published an article on doing this in bash shell, as well - http://cfajohnson.com/shell/articles/dynamically-loadable/

Comment: I followed http://superuser.com/questions/572088/unix-date-command-not-working-for-few-servers which gives me the correct date.